# Magento - Get Best Sellers Product including Soldout Products

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

this is my code but i get only the products that are available in stock. I want to get all products, including the sold-out. Do you have any idea?

```
 $productCount = 5;
        $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); 


$productsBestSellerMens = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')  
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addCategoryFilter($mensID)
            ->setPageSize($productCount);
```

Comment: in a native Magento 1.7, this query doesn't take into account the availability, you can check that by adding `Mage::log($productsBestSellerMens->getSelect()->assemble(), null, 'productsBestSellerMens.log', TRUE);` after your query, run it and open the file YOUR_MAGENTO_ROOT/var/log/productsBestSellerMens.log. It does exclude the bundle/configurable/grouped though, maybe that's your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The comment by OSdave is a good place to start with finding the answer to your question.

At it's heart Magento uses Zend_Db when accessing the database.  As a result you can use the 'magic' [__toString() method of Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.execute.tostring) to output the underlying MySQL query generated by your PHP code.  As category filtering is specific to your situation I've adapted your original code slightly:

```
$productCount   = 5;
$storeId        = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$productsBestSellerMens = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')  
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setPageSize($productCount);

var_dump((string) $productsBestSellerMens->getSelect());
exit;
```

This is a crude but very simple way of finding that the resulting SQL query is:

```
SELECT 
SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty`,
`order_items`.`name` AS `order_items_name`,
`order_items`.`product_id` AS `entity_id`,
`e`.`entity_type_id`,
`e`.`attribute_set_id`,
`e`.`type_id`,
`e`.`sku`,
`e`.`has_options`,
`e`.`required_options`,
`e`.`created_at`,
`e`.`updated_at` 
FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_items` 
INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON `order`.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND `order`.state <> 'canceled' 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped', 'configurable', 'bundle')) AND e.entity_id = order_items.product_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4 
WHERE (parent_item_id IS NULL) 
GROUP BY `order_items`.`product_id` 
HAVING (SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > 0)
```

As you can see from reviewing the query there is nothing that filters 'sold out' products.

You can handle the display of 'sold out' products by using the `isSaleable()` method of the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class.  An example of this in practice is shown within the Magento template file `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`.

It's also worth noting that when I tried to use the same method to pull back a list of best-sellers I found that the results didn't match audited sales data.  A fuller investigation and a corrected method for retrieving best sellers that macth auditedsales data is available on our [blog](http://www.zodiacmedia.co.uk/blog/magento-bestselling-products).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try an extension that will show not only best selling products, but also new/sale/best-selling/most-viewed/top-rated/featured/sold-out products.

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-gallery.html